# Refreshing component after update it at vueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a parent component which has a list component (child) I'm doing a delete operation at child component but when I deleted one of the records records don't be updated unless refreshing the page how I can do it automatically after deleting operation ?

Comment: Can you add your code too pls ?

Comment: The question looks confusing, it is okay to assume the data is on the parent and sent to the child component as props? The delete action takes place on the data within the parent and you want to update the child component to re-render?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need code her to have good overview of you issue... But here is my proposition to handle your issue .

Let's assume you just sent the DELETE request to the back end and receive a positive response. You can directly filter what the list you show in the component .

Example:

myList is is the list you show in template

Id is the identifier of the deleted element

```
myList = myList.filter(element => element.id !== id);
```

With this i think you no more need to refresh the page.